# Ads or offers for in-app purchases that are not clearly distinguishable from your app content

Tags: google-play, google-play-games

I have a letter from Google Play support that update for my game was rejected because of

> Ads or offers for in-app purchases that are not clearly distinguishable from your app content

Does anyone face this rejection?

Since I don't have in-app purchases I believe the reason for me is

> Ads are not clearly distinguishable from your app content

Google Play support attach the screen with violation but I have no idea what is the fix they wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Previous variant

> Description "Watch video and get reward!" and button with text "Watch"

That was not clear enough from the Google Play Team point of view to support [Family Policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335#families-policy) and have a rate 3+.

A working variant which was published successfully

> Description "Watch video ad and get reward!" and button with text "Watch ad"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful as I am facing same issue.

Comment: Very helpful. Google is the worst at communication. Just say, "clearly communicate that user will watch an ad."

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same review of my app [Nonogram Colors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbuonomo.nonogramcolordot) for an update.
Here is the screenshot provided by Google:

[image]

I suppose the wording to watch the video ad is not clear enough for the user. Maybe something like "Watch an ad video to get a reward" could fix the issue. I'll try something like this.

Please keep me in touch is you succeeded to update your app.